# Do abilities based on weapon damage take both one-handers into account?

Tags: diablo-iii

[This](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/60281/how-is-skill-damage-calculated-based-on-weapon-damage) question is good for finding out how damage is calculated precisely.

However, nobody seems to mention something about this: When a skill is based on weapon damage, does it take into account both one handed weapons or only one of them (the main-hand?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you dual wield, you alternate attacks with your weapons. So the damage of your skills will change between each strike. That's why when you equip a significantly lower damage weapon in your offhand, your net damage could possibly go down.

[Source](http://www.osirisguide.com/diablo-3-dual-wield-guide/)