# In Diablo 3 how much does the weapon damage matter for classes that don't do close combat?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How is skill damage calculated based on weapon damage?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/60281/how-is-skill-damage-calculated-based-on-weapon-damage)

Classes like wizard and monk, how much does the damage matter? Should I be more concerned about other things when choosing which weapon to equip?

Comment: @RyanDetzel Thanks for accepting my answer, I'm glad its helpful. If you like the answer, would you please consider upvoting it as well? Votes are generally a more important indication of usefulness and quality than accepting.

Comment: @Beofett LOL. I up-vote you =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weapon damage determines the effectiveness of every damaging skill and ability, including "minions".

If you go to Blizzard's [game guide](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/game/) and look at the class abilities, you will see most spells and abilities say in the description "Deals 80% of weapon damage".

This makes weapon damage important for every class, and ensures that classes dependent on spells and abilities will scale just as well as the classes that rely primarily upon weapon damage.

Answer (score 0):

The weapon you choose is in fact very important, because the damage of that weapon is scaled for your class abilities.  For example, Magic Missle does 110% of your weapon damage as Arcane damage.

[image: Magic Missle]