# Wizard spells and weapon damage

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How is skill damage calculated based on weapon damage?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/60281/how-is-skill-damage-calculated-based-on-weapon-damage)

I just started playing Diablo (first diablo game for me) and I'm trying to understand what makes my spells more powerful. I know intelligence does but does the weapon I have equipped affect all spells damage?

Answer (score 2):

Weapon damage (any weapon) affects spell damage. That means if you just found a shiny new 2-handed axe that does more damage than your puny staff, use it. It makes your spells stronger.

PS: WTF Blizzard...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as you can read from the tooltips, spells do percentage of your weapon as dmg.

Take this for example [Magic Missle](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/active/magic-missile) where it says they do 110% of the weapon dmg as arcane.

Comment: I would like to add the comment that the detailed skill description isn't set by default in the options. I had to manually check that option to show advanced skill descriptions.