# What does 1 intellect translate to damage for a wizard?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How is skill damage calculated based on weapon damage?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/60281/how-is-skill-damage-calculated-based-on-weapon-damage)

I am currently comparing items to see which is better and the bonus difference is damage or intellect...  If an item has X intellect, what does that translate into damage?

Example (which is better):

**Item 1:**
+2 intellect

**Item 2:**
3-4 Damage

Which one of the two items is better?

Comment: See also: [This](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67843/what-does-the-damage-stat-on-the-character-sheet-actually-mean-how-is-it-calcul)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: Flat out damage is better than intelligence, though having high amounts of both is obviously beneficial.

Each point of intelligence increases your damage by 1%. For example, right now I have 846 intelligence, which enhances my base damage by 846%. However, the base DPS of the weapon you are using is much more important than strictly intelligence bonuses, as the damage of your weapon is what that intelligence modifier is being applied to.