# Does increased Sweeping Wind damage apply to each level?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

I have seen some items that give a damage bonus to Sweeping Wind.  Does this bonus apply to each level of Sweeping Wind or does it divide the bonus up between the three levels?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is skill damage calculated based on weapon damage?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/60281/how-is-skill-damage-calculated-based-on-weapon-damage)

Comment: @bwarner: I disagree. This question is asking about a very specific skill, with a unique constraint. Although it's possible someone could provide an answer which covers Origami's question in the original question,  I do not believe that it is reasonable to expect that since a question which covers every special case would be too broad imo.

Comment: I agree, this is kind of a specific situation. Hopefully the tweak to the question title will make it a bit clearer.

Answer (score 3):

It will increase the actual damage dealt by Sweeping Wind by 5%. So it does not matter how many stacks you have or what rune you are using.