# When is Pierce the Veil counted in your damage?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-witch-doctor

[Pierce the veil](http://www.diablowiki.net/Pierce_the_Veil) offers a 20% boost to my damage, which seems interesting. But I don't know when it is counted. If this is on my base damage, it is pointless because I get 1200% from intelligence. If it is after the intelligence boost however, it gives a much larger boost.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is skill damage calculated based on weapon damage?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/60281/how-is-skill-damage-calculated-based-on-weapon-damage)

Comment: Per the linked question, they all multiply together, so it does multiply your 1200% too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My WD's damage stat goes up by exactly 20% when I spec Pierce the Veil.  It's a +20% multiplier that's applied separately from the Intelligence bonus.  It doesn't matter when 20% is applied, since multiplication is commutative.