# Do items that increase skill based damage factor into displayed DPS

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

I recently equipped a helm that increased my monk's crippling wave damage by 10%.  The displayed DPS did not change nor did it change when i swap out crippling wave for a different skill.  Is this a known issue? Is there another way to determine the DPS when using an item that increases skill based damage.

Comment: Skill descriptions won't get updated from increased damage affixes.  The DPS on the paper doll also won't take skills into account at all; it's all equipment based.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the Damage attribute on the character sheet does not take into account skills or equipment that boosts particular skills at all.  You would need to determine the DPS yourself, following the formulas at [How is skill damage calculated based on weapon damage?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/60281/how-is-skill-damage-calculated-based-on-weapon-damage).

Comment: Good edit on my answer on a different question :) and good answer here +1.  Very helpful man.