# How do you calculate bonus damage to skills in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

When I equip an item that grants an additional bonus damage to a particular skill (i.e. a 2H Bow that gives +10% damage to Witch Doctor's Fire Bats), I do not see that bonus damage reflected in the character sheet DPS.

Because I cannot visually see the damage increase, it got me wondering whether or not the calculation was a straight forward increase (damage * 110%) or if there was a much more complicated formula that would result in a lower than expected actual damage output when using the skill.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do items that increase skill based damage factor into displayed DPS](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/76421/do-items-that-increase-skill-based-damage-factor-into-displayed-dps)

Comment: @fbueckert reading through the answers, I did not see any mention of +skill damage from items, so I personally feel this is not a duplicate.

Comment: You're asking a two-part question here.  1) Does the extra damage from item skill boosts show up as part of your DPS?  and 2) How is this extra damage calculated.  The first part has already been asked, and linked.  The second part, however, I believe is OK.  If you can edit your question to limit it just to how it gets calculated, that'd be great.  Also, in regards to duplicates, the correct approach is to request an updated/new answer; asking the same question again just because there's no answers that help you is frowned upon.

Comment: The second part has already been asked and answered as well.  See the link in the accepted answer to the first part.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is skill damage calculated based on weapon damage?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/60281/how-is-skill-damage-calculated-based-on-weapon-damage)

Answer (score 1):

This will not increase dps in the character sheet as it doesn't show you this skill does that much dps and the other one deals that much dps.

When you equip an item with an affix, let's say +10% dmg to Bola Shot which deals 130% weapon dmg before the bonus. After you equip the item with the affix Bola Shot will be calculated  as a 140% weapon dmg.

Your DPS in the character sheet is calculated with attack dmg, attack speed, crit dmg, crit chance. I do not have any source linking to this, just the math I did.